# wxPython/wxWidgets very long scroll area with thumbnails

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a vertical list of image thumbnails that could potentially reach hundreds/thousands of images. Is there a recommended strategy in wxPython/wxWidgets that would allow for efficient loading of the list so that all images aren't required to be loaded immediately. On iOS, there is the concept of cell reuse in a `UITableView` and I wasn't sure if there was anything similar here or if the recommended solution is just to preload all of them. I also considered loading a default image and then loading the images in a separate thread.

Here is a prototype that shows what I'm trying to accomplish (with the red boxes replace with image thumbnails)

[image]

Here is the code that I used to generate the prototype:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel

eng = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='wxPython')

main_panel = wx.Panel(frame)
main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
main_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

left_panel = ScrolledPanel(main_panel)
left_panel.SetupScrolling()
left_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,255,0))
left_panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
left_panel.SetSizer(left_panel_sizer)
main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

right_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel)
right_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(0,0,255))
main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 4, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

for i in range(1000):
    left_panel_sizer.AddSpacer(10)
    thumbnail = wx.Panel(left_panel)
    thumbnail.SetMinSize((175,240))
    thumbnail.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,0,0))
    left_panel_sizer.Add(thumbnail, 3, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER)
    left_panel_sizer.AddSpacer(10)


frame.Show()
frame.SetSize(1440,875)
frame.CenterOnScreen()

eng.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Did you take a look at wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl?

Comment: @Infinity77 I hadn't considered that since I was looking to prototype something in wxPython and eventually rebuild it in wxWidgets. I also didn't know about it beforehand. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [VZ's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288517/107183) suggestion, I realized that manually drawing only the visible thumbnails would be the best solution.

There were several classes that could accomplish this in wxpython: `wx.VListBox`, `wx.VScrolledWindow`, or `wx.ScrolledWindow`

`wx.VListBox` provided the simplest API. You created a custom subclass and implemented `OnMeasureItem` to specify the cell height and `OnDrawItem` specify
the drawing code just for your item. The downside of this approach was that the scrolling would 'lock' in position at the top of each item. `wx.VScrolledWindow` had this same issue with locked scroll position with a slightly different API that could be useful in other contexts.

`wx.ScrolledWindow` was the most useful since it solved the problem of locked scroll position. But it involved a little calculation to only draw the cells that were in view. Below is the prototype that implements this:

```
import wx

class ThumbnailView(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.VScrolledWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.ScrollRate = 10
        self.ThumbnailHeight = 100
        self.NumThumbnails = 100000

        self.SetVirtualSize(-1, self.ThumbnailHeight*self.NumThumbnails)
        self.SetScrollRate(0, self.ScrollRate)

    def OnDraw(self, dc):
        width, height = self.GetSize()

        # Calculate min and max thumbnails in view
        min_visible_thumb = int((self.GetViewStart()[1]*self.ScrollRate) / self.ThumbnailHeight)
        max_visible_thumb = min_visible_thumb + int(height / self.ThumbnailHeight) + 2

        # TEMP - Print min/max visible thumbnails
        print(f"min_visible_thumb = {min_visible_thumb}")
        print(f"max_visible_thumb = {max_visible_thumb}")
        print(f"height = {height}")

        for n in range(min_visible_thumb, max_visible_thumb):
            # Define the thumnail rectangle
            r = wx.Rect(0, n*100, width, 100)
            
            # Set the color alternate between red, green, or blue
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(255 * (n % 3 == 0), 255 * (n % 3 == 1), 255 * (n % 3 == 2))))
            
            # Draw the background
            dc.DrawRectangle(r)

            # Draw the text label
            dc.SetTextForeground(wx.WHITE)
            dc.DrawLabel(str(n), r, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

eng = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title='wxPython')

main_panel = wx.Panel(frame)
main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
main_panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

left_panel = ThumbnailView(main_panel)
main_sizer.Add(left_panel, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

right_panel = wx.Panel(main_panel)
main_sizer.Add(right_panel, 4, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 0)

frame.Show()
frame.SetSize(1440,875)
frame.CenterOnScreen()

eng.MainLoop()
```

Here's the screenshot of the prototype:

[image: wxPython prototype wx.Scrolled]

This approach scales very well to thousands, tens of thousands, or a hundred thousand rows while only needing to draw the displayed rows.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid creating thousands of windows. Instead, draw the images yourself -- which will also allow you to load them on demand.

Then you can easily have millions (or more) of items in the list, see e.g. `wxHtmlListBox` which uses this approach.